# Unwrapping Mesh Hair

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I want to UV unwrap this hair mesh, and then texture it with a procedural Wave texture (parallel lines). I want the lines to converge to the tip of each spike of hair.

[image: MeshHair]

It seems that I could do something like mark seams on sharp edges (or edge split modifier, unwrap, and remove doubles) to get the main pieces of the surface separated. But I do not know how to get them oriented to match the directions of the Wave lines cleanly, or how to change their tips to get the texture to converge probably.

What workflow would let me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unwrap individual segments, then using <kbd>P</kbd> button to add some pinned vertices in the UV/Image editor to control the shape to match the wave texture while using Live Unwrap.

[image]

[image]