# Automatic UV Unwrapping with Scaling on Specific Faces

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've successfully unwrapped a UV map of my mesh. From here, I intend to hand-paint a texture which will use the UV Map. My problem now is that I want the surfaces to share a proportional amount of pixels on the texture surface, unlike here where the UV of the face is too tightly-packed that the texture is being stretched on the model.

Is there an automatic way of doing this so that I don't need to perform the scaling manually? Thank you!

[image: UV Unwrap]

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a seam on the neck where it's not so visible, then you can separate the head from the torso and, that should result in more even texture distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider doing that if I fail to find an automatic solution to it.

Comment: You can pin some control points and use live unwrap to adjust the scale http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28028/unwrapping-mesh-hair/28352